# How to expand macro definition during concatenation?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
> cat | cpp -c
#define ORDER 3
#define APPEND_ORDER(name) name ## _ ## ORDER

void APPEND_ORDER(cg)(int arg)
{}
^D
```

I see that the macro `ORDER` is *not* being expanded during the parameter replacement.  But that's what I want!

```
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"



void cg_ORDER(int arg)
{}
```

Desired output:

```
void cg_3(int arg)
{}
```